# How to propagate an Exception from a Task / Thread to the method that created this Task in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, async-await, task-parallel-library

I do not know how I should properly propagate an exception from a Task to the thread that created this task:

```
private void threadMT()
{
    Task task;
    try
    {
        task = new Task(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception("blabla");
        });
        task.Start();

        while(!task.IsCompleted)
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        if (task.IsFaulted)
            throw task.Exception;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

When this line is reached:

```
throw new Exception("blabla");
```

the app halts saying that the exception is not handled.
Can it be propagated back to method?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for you to propagate an exception from a `Task` executed on the thread-pool is to turn it to actually return a `Task` which you can `await` on:

```
public async Task AwaitOnTaskAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await DoStuffWithThreadAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}

public Task DoStuffWithThreadAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception("blabla"); });
}
```

`await` will make sure to unwrap the exception out of the `Task`, allowing you to apply a `try-catch` on it.

Side Note - Don't use the `Task` constructor, instead use `Task.Run` to return a "hot task" (one which has already started). There's no point in creating a `Task` which you're actively blocking on using `Thread.Sleep` later on, either execute it synchronously or use async-await to asynchronously wait on the task.

Comment: This code still generates an "unhandled exception".

Comment: Do you have first chance exceptions turned on in VS?

Comment: No more exceptions if I disable CLR exceptions in VS options.
I am not sure about all of the consequences of disabling this?

Comment: It's simply an aid for you to see any exceptions thrown, even if you `catch` them later. It helps in debugging your code.